# max height of binary search tree

Tags: java

so I need to find the max height of a binary tree but for some reason the result of the code provided below is off by 1. 
For example if the max height is 3 the following code will give me 2.
if the max height is 4 the result will be 3. 
I am not sure why? the root is not considered for the calculations of the max height therefore i set leftCounter and rightCounter to be 0.
any ideas?

```
public int getMaxHeight(BST.TreeNode<E> n) {
    if(n == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int leftCounter = 0;
    int rightCounter = 0;
    if(n.left != null) {
        leftCounter = getMaxHeight(n.left) +1 ;
    }
    if(n.right != null) {
        rightCounter = getMaxHeight(n.right) +1 ;
    }

    if(leftCounter > rightCounter) {
        return leftCounter;
    }   
    else 
        return rightCounter;    

}
```

the max height of this binary tree should be **3**: 
  because of the elements 5,9,11. the root is not counted for the max 
  height.

```
        15
   _____|____
   10       21 
___|___    __|__ 
9    14   16   24
                |__
                  25
```

Comment: It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a sample binary tree and specify the max height it should have and why it should be that number (and not one number above or below it).

Comment: Because you're not considering the `root` node just return `1+Max(....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code actually returns the correct value; it's just that you misunderstand what the height of a tree means. The height is the number of *edges* on the longest path from root to leaf, not the number of *nodes* on the path. So the following tree

```
        3
   _____|____
   4         5 
___|___    __|__ 
6     7    8   9
```

has a height of 2, not 3. What you are looking for is the number of *levels* in the tree, not the height.

```
public int getNumberOfLevels(BST.TreeNode<E> n) {
    if(n == null) return 0;
    int left = getNumberOfLevels(n.left);
    int right = getNumberOfLevels(n.right);
    return 1 + Math.max(left, right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize leftCounter, and RightCounter by 1. Reason being if(n==null) -> false 
which means height is atleast 1